# Swift lazy var reference cycle

Tags: swift

I have a class

```
class SomeClass {
    lazy var property1: Int = {
        return 1
    }()

    lazy var property2: Int = {
       return self.property1
    }()

    deinit {
        print("SomeClass will be destroyed")
    }
}
```

If I have the following in playground:

```
var a: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
print(a?.property1)
print(a?.property2)
a =  nil
```

then the variable `a` will be deinitialized as `SomeClass will be destroyed` message will appear. 
However if I comment out the accesses to the properties like:

```
var a: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
//print(a?.property1)
//print(a?.property2)
a =  nil
```

I still got the message `SomeClass will be destroyed`.
I would expect that there is a reference cycle as the closure of  `property2` is never called and it references `self` through `self.property1`.

Is there something special with `lazy` variables or just my assumption is wrong that `property2` hold a reference to `self`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that there isn't is a reference cycle is because the closure isn't stored on `a`. If `a` stored the closure and the closure contained self then there would be a reference cycle.

For lazy properties, everything after the `=` isn't called until the first time you access `property2`. When you do, the closure is created, called, freed from memory, and then the value is returned to you. This is why you can get rid of the `self.` in the closure since it will never capture self.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense! Do you have a reference however on the first part, that the closure isn't stored on `a`? Or where is it stored?

Comment: Since the closure is immediately called, it isn't stored anywhere. It's no different than just calling a function for getting the initial value. ie `lazy var property2: Int = someValue()`